# bokeh 0.12.14 and flask, getting 404 error in AjaxDataSource post call

Tags: flask, bokeh

I am new to bokeh. I am struggling to get around error 404 when using AjaxDataSource . Following is the simple code which will update the plot every 2 seconds.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
from bokeh.embed import components
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models.sources import AjaxDataSource
app = Flask(__name__)
x = 0
@app.route('/data/', methods=['POST'])
def data():
    global x
    x += 1
    y = 2 ** x
    return jsonify(x=x, y=y)

@app.route("/dash")
def showChanges():
    plots = []
    plots.append(funcEmbedFig())

    return render_template('extendTest.html', plots=plots)

def funcEmbedFig():
    source = AjaxDataSource(data_url=request.url_root + 'data/',
                            polling_interval=2000, mode='append')

    source.data = dict(x=[], y=[])

    plot = figure(plot_height=300, sizing_mode='scale_width')
    plot.line('x', 'y', source=source, line_width=4)

    script, div = components(plot)
    return script, div


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

How can I get around this?

Any help would be much useful,
Thanks.

Comment: Could you show your `extendTest.html` file?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried flask’s `url_for(“data”)` as the `data_url` parameter?

Comment: I am not able to reproduce any error. Your code actually works as is (without the `url_for("data")`) if I just define a template file and call it `extendTest.html`. Could it be an issue with how you're firing up your flask server?

Comment: Tudor, sorry for late reply, I still cant figure out the problem. Could you please tell convenient time for screen sharing so that I can get through it? It'll be really helpful.